# The words מעשה אבות סימן לבנים

Tags: sources-mekorot, avot-patriarch-fathers, quotations

Where do the words מעשה אבות סימן לבנים come from?

Comment: Where did you encounter them?

Comment: The origins of this phrase are traced on or near p. 607 of [דרכי האגדה והמדרש](https://books.google.com.au/books?id=f5_XAAAAMAAJ&source=gbs_book_other_versions).

Comment: @ WAF: Can you please provide me with a link for that sefer?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Interestingly, although widely quoted, a cursory search shows me only 16th century sources for this exact wording, although they quote "*Chazal*".

E.g. R. Isaiah Horowitz in *Shelah* to Parshat Vayishlach:

> כי אם על יוצאי חלציו גם כן, כי מעשה אבות סימן לבנים

"But to his descendants as well, for the act of the ancestors is an indicator for the descendants."

And [R. Samuel Eidels](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maharsha) in *Maharsha* (Chiddushei Aggadot) to Gittin 57b:

> כלפי מה שאמרו כי מעשה אבות סימן לבנים
>   "Corresponding to what they said that the act of the ancestors is an indicator for the descendants."

Although the exact wording differs, the Midrash Tanchuma (Lech L'cha: 9) states:

> סימן נתן לו הקב"ה לאברהם שכל מה שארע לו ארע לבניו

"God gave Abraham sign that whatever would occur to him would occur to his descendants."

As noted by @davidkenner, Ramban quotes the Tanchuma in his commentary to Genesis (12: 6):

> אמרו (תנחומא ט) כל מה שאירע לאבות סימן לבנים

Comment: This answer in regard to Ramban is simply wrong. Try actually looking at his commentary to Bereshit 12:6. http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=9597&st=&pgnum=168      It does not cite Tanchuma explicitly. That note was likely added by by some editor. Also Ramban is late 12th to early 13th century. What's more, the Midrash Tanchuma (also called Tanchuma A and the Buber edition) is dated to the 5th century or the 8th century on the outside.

Comment: Taking this just a little further, the principle of מעשה אבות סימן לבנים is brought in several places in Bereshit Rabbah (43:3 and 52:7 in regard to Avraham, and 68:12 and 78:8 in regard to Yaacov). That is according to most views composed between the 3rd and 5th century. It is always quoting the Rabbanim.

Comment: `in regard to Ramban is simply wrong.` How so? ` It does not cite Tanchuma explicitly` I never said it did. Perhaps I should make this even clearer, lest anyone else misread it. `is dated to the 5th century or the 8th century` The dating of Tanhuma and its various variants is indeed a debated topic. How that invalidates my answer, is a mystery. | Remember that the OP asked where the particular expression comes from. I answered this, and indeed gave some extra background. I fail to see how the question has not been answered. @YaacovDeane

Comment: If I misunderstood your answer, I apologize. It seems to be suggesting that the expression is very late, even perhaps as late as the 16th century. But the Midrash Rabbah is written by an Amora (3rd century) bringing much earlier teachings. Also, what is the @davidkenner reference? Was that supposed to be a link?

Comment: Evidently his comment was deleted. The question was about the expression; not related ideas, but the expression. If you have evidence that the answer is wrong, please indicate that. I see none in any of your comments. It all seems to be about the idea, a fascinating point in its own right. If you are interested in this point consider asking a separate question about it. Consider also not downvtoting posts that answer the OP's question, just because you think that the OP should have asked a different question. @YaacovDeane

Comment: @YaacovDeane It seems pretty rude to downvote, and then ignore comments, that your claims seem irrelevant to this post answering the question.

Comment: It's not meant as rude. The primary point is your opening statement that gives the impression the phrase and concept are a relatively new innovation. It isn't. Like is reflected both in the actual words of Ramban and the citations from Bereshit Rabbah, this is a longstanding teaching of the Rabbanim. The answer, to be accurate, can definitely be improved. And the davidkenner reference is no longer relevant.

Comment: Or to clarify, the traditional Jewish teaching is that all these hermeneutical rules of interpretation are actually a tradition that was given to us by Moshe Rabbeinu. That includes this 'great general principle' of מעשה אבות סימן לבנים.

Comment: `is your opening statement that gives the impression the phrase and concept` The OP asked `where do the words come from` I answered "a cursory search shows me only 16th century sources **for this exact wording**" but proceed to show that in contradistinction to that exact phase, the _idea_ seems to be older `Although the exact wording differs, the Midrash Tanchuma (Lech L'cha: 9) states...`. It seems difficult to understand how anyone could possibly read the first sentence as claiming that the idea has no precedent before the 16th century. Given that the very next sentence states the opposite.

Comment: @YaacovDeane ^^^ Now that your elementary reading comprehension mistake has been identified consider revoking your downvote. | The fact that your pontificating about `Or to clarify, the traditional Jewish teaching` is likely wrong is irrelevant to all of the above, so I don't intend to address it.

Comment: You aren't making any statement that the idea appears to be older. You only list Midrash Tanchuma and Ramban. In the context, of your answer, that sounds like they are also around the 16th century. Considering the broad audience that participates on this site, many people who don't know the history that well would come to the wrong conclusion. You may intend what you say, but it isn't coming through in what you are writing. Also, do you not want to bring out the primary idea, that these types of hermeneutical rules come to us from Moshe Rabbeinu? That seems to be the main point.

Comment: You don't seem to be reading my comments. This isn't about what I personally world like to talk about.it's about answering the question.which I did, and then some... @YaacovDeane the main point is to answer the question asked, not to pontificate.